# spark.kafka.poll.time in MapR stream consumers

Tags: spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am working with MapR streams and setting the parameter "spark.kafka.poll.time" in my direct kafka API consumer; However, I don't know exactly what is the meaning of this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

According to the MapR documention is the query interval time for a consumer on the MapR Streams (http://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/Spark/Spark_IntegrateMapRStreams_Consume.html). Mostly you have to specify it only when using Spark Streaming to connect to Kafka. In a standard Java Kafka Consumer, on the poll method, there is a interval in millis that you have to specify it, so there could be an analogy between the two of them.

For Java:

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(consumerPoolTime);
```

For Spark Streaming as Map params:

```
"spark.kafka.poll.time" -> "300",
// other params

KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```